# Работа с большими объемами данных

Tags: c, сортировка, файлы

Подскажите как корректно внести изменения в программу, чтобы можно было работать с большим объемом информации. А то сейчас при больших объемах сталкиваюсь с переполнением памяти и краш программы.

Суть такая:

В директории есть файлы, в которых есть ID текстовой строки и сама строка. Во всех файлах ІД строк уникальные и возрастают монотонно по мере добавления новых записей в файл. Мне надо открыть все файлы, посортировать строки по мере возростания ID и записать все данные в один файл.

Код моей программы:

```
#define MESSAGE_LENGTH 10000

struct list {
unsigned long id;
char data[MESSAGE_LENGTH];
};
int openFileAndAddToList(struct list items[], long numberOfLines);
long numberOfEntries(); //от этой функции я потом избавлюсь
void writeToFile(struct list items[],long size);
void sorting(struct list items[], long l,long u);
long partArr(struct list items[],long l,long u);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
long listSize;
listSize = numberOfEntries(); //calculates size of list array
struct list items[listSize];
openFileAndAddToList(items, listSize);
printf("Merging...\n");
sorting(items,0 , listSize-1);
writeToFile(items,listSize);
printf("Done!\n");
printf("___________________________________________________________\n");
printf("All data written in \"all.log\" file at program root folder.\n");
printf("___________________________________________________________\n");
return 0;
}

long numberOfEntries()
{
DIR* FD;
struct dirent* oneFile;
FILE* sourceFile;
char  buffer[BUFSIZ];
long numberOfLines;
FD = opendir("./callLog");
if (FD != NULL){
    while ((oneFile = readdir(FD))){
        if (!strcmp (oneFile->d_name, "."))
            continue;
        if (!strcmp (oneFile->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        if (!strcmp (oneFile->d_name, ".DS_Store"))
            continue;
        char fullFileName [255];
        strcpy(fullFileName,"./callLog/");
        strcat(fullFileName, oneFile->d_name);
        sourceFile = fopen(fullFileName, "rw");
        if (sourceFile == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error : Can`t open source file - %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        while (fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, sourceFile) != NULL)
        {
            numberOfLines++;
        }

    }

}
fclose(sourceFile);
return numberOfLines;
}

int openFileAndAddToList(struct list items[], long numberOfLines)
{
DIR* FD;
struct dirent* oneFile;
FILE    *sourceFile;
char    buffer[BUFSIZ];
int k = 0;
FD = opendir("./callLog");
if (FD != NULL){
    while ((oneFile = readdir(FD))){
        if (!strcmp (oneFile->d_name, "."))
            continue;
        if (!strcmp (oneFile->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        if (!strcmp (oneFile->d_name, ".DS_Store"))
            continue;
        char fullFileName [255];
        strcpy(fullFileName,"./callLog/");
        strcat(fullFileName, oneFile->d_name);
        printf("Opening file: %s \n",fullFileName);
        sourceFile = fopen(fullFileName, "rw");
        if (sourceFile == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error : Can`t open source file - %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        while (fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, sourceFile) != NULL)
        {
            sscanf(buffer, "%lu",&items[k].id);
            size_t numbers_end = strspn(buffer, "1234567890. \t");
            strcpy(items[k].data, buffer+numbers_end);
            k++;
        }
        fclose(sourceFile);
    }
}
return 0;
}


void writeToFile(struct list items[],long size)
{
FILE    *sourceFile;
sourceFile = fopen("all.log", "w");
if (sourceFile == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error : Failed to open destination file - %s\n", strerror(errno));

}
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    fprintf(sourceFile,"%lu %s", items[i].id, items[i].data);
}
fclose(sourceFile);
}
```

Для сортировки использую алгоритм быстрой сортировки. 
Прошу дать пинка в нужном направлении.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего записать все данные в один файл (с ID в первом поле), а потом отсортировать командой `sort`.

Что же касается программы, то во первых, можно сэкономить память, изменив структуру на

```
struct list {
  unsigned long id;
  char *data;
};
```

т.е. хранить в сортируемом массиве указатели на строки, которые надо размещать в динамической память. Тогда текст каждой строки  будет занимать не `MESSAGE_LENGTH` байт, а столько, сколько Вы реально прочли (плюс небольшая добавка).

После этого, также надо заменить в функции `openFileAndAddToList()`

```
strcpy(items[k].data, buffer+numbers_end);
```

на

```
items[k].data = strdup(buffer+numbers_end);
```

Во вторых, Вы размещаете в `main()` свой огромный(?) массив

```
struct list items[listSize];
```

в локальной памяти функции (т.е. в стеке), которая обычно ограничена несколькими мегабайтами (типично 2 или 8 MB, вообще зависит от настроек системы).

Но массив можно разместить в динамической памяти, которая обычно значительно больше (сейчас типично гигабайты).

Внимательно код на смотрел, но мне кажется, что можно так

```
struct list *items = malloc(sizeof(struct list) * listSize);
```

IMHO оба улучшения решат эту задачку.

Comment: Увидел свои ошибки. Да, весь массив я обьявил в стеке... Что, наверное, главная ошибка в программе.